# Flutter type 'String' is not subtype of type 'FutureOr<Model>' , Response Json Without Key

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, future, provider

I'm trying to call the service like this, I think something wrong over here because the "result" return Future and cant assign to String, or how to parse Future to String?
and MyApi return Json without Key Something like this

> body

```
ReturnStatus
```

so I'm trying to store the response directly into the user var, but still not working

> UI (Button Login)

```
login.loginProcess
    ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
    : RaisedButton(
        color: myPrimaryColor,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Login",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontFamily: "NunitoSansBold")),
          ],
        ),
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
        onPressed: () {
          print("clicked Button Login");
          **login.authenticationUser(context);**
        },
      ),
```

> Service

```
class AuthService {
  Future<User> authenticateUser(String id, String password) async {
    var user;
    try {
      final resAuth = await http.post(
        "${BaseUrl.auth}api/AuthenticateUser",
        body: {"login": id, "password": password},
      );
      if (resAuth.statusCode == 200) {
        user = resAuth.body;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return user;
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

> Provider with ChangeNotifier (For handling the business logic and stuf)

```
authenticationUser(BuildContext context) async {
  if (_controllerEmail.text != "" && _controllerPassword.text != "") {
    loginProcess = true;
    final ioc = new HttpClient();
    ioc.badCertificateCallback =
        (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
    //TODO StoredSharedPreference
    SharedPreferences _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    try {
      AuthService authService = new AuthService();
      var result = authService.authenticateUser(
          _controllerEmail.text, _controllerPassword.text);
      showSnackBar(result);
      _preferences.setString("status", "seen");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      showSnackBar(result.toString());
    }
    loginProcess = false;
  } else {
    autoValidate = true;
  }
}
```

> Model

```
class User {
  String status;
  String id;
  String userName;

  User({
    this.status,
    this.id,
    this.userName,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      User(status: json["status"], id: json["id"], userName: json["userName"]);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {"status": status, "id": id, "userName": userName};
}
```

=======UPDATE , Change the method authenticationUser (add await)=======

> Service

```
class AuthService {
  Future<User> authenticateUser(String id, String password) async {
    var user;
    try {
      final resAuth = await http.post(
        "${BaseUrl.auth}api/AuthenticateUser",
        body: {"login": id, "password": password},
      );
      if (resAuth.statusCode == 200) {
        user = resAuth.body;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return user;
      // throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

> Provider

```
authenticationUser(BuildContext context) async {
    if (_controllerEmail.text != "" && _controllerPassword.text != "") {
      loginProcess = true;
      final ioc = new HttpClient();
      ioc.badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
      //TODO StoredSharedPreference
      SharedPreferences _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      try {
        AuthService authService = new AuthService();
        var result = await authService.authenticateUser(
            _controllerEmail.text, _controllerPassword.text);
        _preferences.setString("status", "seen");
        showSnackBar(result.toString());
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        /* showSnackBar(e.toString());*/
      }
      loginProcess = false;
    } else {
      autoValidate = true;
    }
  }
```

in catch (e) {
print(e);

value of e is
`String' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<User>'`

==Update Add Image Value from resAuth==

> [resAuthValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb2wA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add `await`.

```
var result = await authService.authenticateUser(
          _controllerEmail.text, _controllerPassword.text);
```

---

**Edit**

Change your `authenticateUser` method to this

```
Future authenticateUser(String id, String password) async {
    var user;
    try {
      final resAuth = await http.post(
        "${BaseUrl.auth}api/AuthenticateUser",
        body: {"login": id, "password": password},
      );
      if (resAuth.statusCode == 200) {
        return resAuth.body;
      }
    } catch (e) {
     return false;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Change provider code as below

```
 try {
        AuthService authService = new AuthService();
        var result = await authService.authenticateUser(
            _controllerEmail.text, _controllerPassword.text);
        _preferences.setString("status", "seen");
        if(result!=false)
        showSnackBar(result.toString());
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        /* showSnackBar(e.toString());*/
      }
```

Comment: trying to add await, now I cant store the user value while doing try-catch on method authenticationUser , going through to catch and get type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<User>'

Comment: please update your post by pasting latest code and errors.

Comment: `print(e.toString());` will do the tricks.

Comment: got same result catch (e) { print(e.toString());

Comment: can you print `resAuth`  in `AuthService`? see what value you get.

Comment: hmm , i got this  ```Instance of 'Response'```

Comment: how about `restAuth.body` ? Probably `restAuth` dont have `statusCode`.

Comment: resAuth has a statusCode for sure , add a image for resAuth value while debuging

Comment: you can't return `restAuth.body` as it is expected to return `Future<User>`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: so I am no need make the value assigned to the model then? okay thank you, it's work